# Recreating iTunes .itl database from .xml file without itunes copying songs?

Tags: itunes, import

I have a Library.xml file, and want have its contents in iTunes.  If I follow the recommended "File -> Library -> Import Playlist" option for this, it tries to copy all my songs into the iTunes Media folder, probably because my Library.xml file references all its songs on a networked drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the one step I was forgetting was to reset the iTunes settings after removing my .itl database and library .xml files so that iTunes did not "organize your library" and "copy songs to itunes media folder after adding to library".